# Linux machine refuse to boot with invalid elf header

Tags: linux, headers, crash, boot

Recently, after a power supply crash problem, my linux machine (Centos 5.5 X64) did not boot neither gnome nor shell. On gnome startup it shows this error:

```
/etc/X11/prefdm: line 16: :/etc/sysconfig/desktop: cannot execute binary file /usr/bin/rhgb-client: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/lib64/libpopt.so.0 invalid ELF header
```

I tried rescue disk, but it couldnt recognize my OS! There is a chance that this problem is caused by hard disk problem. Cause of when I tried to boot OS from runlevel 3, some error regarding to Raid disk and hard drive appeared and disappeared fast which I could not read all of them, after these errors disappeared a Hello World page shows up that nothing can be done. I am using hardware Raid on this machine (intel storage matrix).

Could somebody please help me for booting this machine? I have some important services running on this machine which I need it fast.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the library:

```
yum whatprovides libpopt.so.0
yum install <best result from above command>
```